# How many users can be logged in spring boot?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, boot

I have a spring boot application, I'm not really sure how users and threads work

The number of users depends on the application itself or tomcat?

Can I have more than 100,000 users at the same time in the application? What does it depend on?

How can I control the application so that there are no problems with the number of users at the same time?

Comment: `I'm not really sure how users and threads work` then i suggest you google and start reading. wikipedia is a good place to start.

Answer (score 2):

It depends, my mate!

There are basically 2 most common ways of securing your web application: **stateless** and **stateful**.

If you're using **stateless** (For example **JWT**, which contains all authentication & authorization information), and every single request is re-authenticated & authorized when it reaches your application, and you don't have to store it anywhere, then you can basically have an infinite number of users logging in at the same time.

If you're using a **stateful** way to do this (For example the **session-id**, which is just a random string), then, in this case, you HAVE to store the session data somewhere, so that when you see that **session-id** in the request, you can use it to retrieve the current state of that session. In this case, it depends on your storage.

Comment: And threads have nothing to do with this.